# Performing an HTTP PATCH using Ruby curb

Tags: ruby, rest, curl, curb

I'm trying to do an HTTP PATCH using curb. Looking through the code, there doesn't seem to be a method exposed for this. Is there any way to use curb to do a PATCH? If not, what other libraries or methods are there in Ruby to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With curb latest version (v0.8.1) `PATCH` is supported even though it is not explicitly available within the `Curl::Easy` interface (see `lib/curl/easy.rb`).

You can find a shortcut method [here](https://github.com/taf2/curb/blob/master/lib/curl.rb#L32):

```
# see lib/curl.rb
module Curl
  # ...
  def self.patch(url, params={}, &block)
    http :PATCH, url, postalize(params), nil, &block
  end
  # ...
end
```

With it you can perform a `PATCH` request as follow:

```
curl = Curl.patch("http://www.example.com/baz", {:foo => "bar"})
```

Under the hood, the `PATCH` verb is simply passed to the easy interface as follow:

```
curl = Curl::Easy.new(url)

# `http` is a method implemented within the C extensions of curb
# see `ruby_curl_easy_perform_verb_str`. It allows to set the HTTP
# verb by calling `curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, verb)`
# and perform the request right after
curl.http(:PATCH)
```